# How to multiple background video downloads in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, download, background-process

I have an iOS application, where I need to download over 60-70 videos a week of size 3-8MB each.
The issue is, how do I download these videos?
I am storing the list of videos and urls in a database.

Possible solutions:

Use a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`, call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` as soon as the app starts. This task will download one video.
In the `endBackgroundTask` I will mark that particular video as downloaded.
Concerns here are, can I start multiple `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`?
Where should I start them? In AppDelegate? A particular controller?
If I start it in a particular controller, on `viewDidLoad()` what will happen if the app exits?

Please guide me or provide an alternate solution.
Thanks

Comment: Solution A sounds good, what is your Solution B then? there is Solution B, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AFNetworking` as `ASIHTTPRequest`  is `deprecated`.

Refer [AFNetworking source](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) link.

Also refer [afnetworking-downloading-multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409122/afnetworking-downloading-multiple-files) link and [Does AFNetworking have backgrounding support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881866/1106035) link.

**EDIT** : start downloading in `AppDelegate`

Check [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) for resumable download.

Refer [afnetworking-pause-resume-downloading-big-files using AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173744/afnetworking-pause-resume-downloading-big-files) link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also want to know, where do you call this function? In the AppDelegate or in a particular controller? Also, what happens if the app is quit before the download finishes?
 Thanks

Comment: Awesome, Im almost there, one last question?
I have to download multiple files, so what I will do is have a for loop and start the download for every file one after the other, using one of the above solutions, anything wrong with that or any alternate solution to it?
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can download multiple files with [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) in the background. See the documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

Please note that `ASIHTTPRequest` is no longer working so you can use `AFNetworking`.

> `AFNetworking` is a delightful networking library for iOS and Mac OS `. It's built on top of`NSURLConnection`,`NSOperation`, and other familiar`Foundation technologies`. It has a modular architecture with well-designed, feature-rich APIs that are a joy to use.

Find the SDK [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).