# How to load tables of information faster using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Currently I am loading all of my `UITableViewControllers` with images and text. I'm not sure if there is a way of shortening my loading times. I'm thinking that GCD might be the best route to go, however, I'm not too sure that I'm using this correctly:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [some method];

    });
```

This is being loaded in the `ViewDidLoad`, and I'm unsure if this is the correct place to use GCD. Also, **is this correct way of asynchronously loading information?**

Comment: What do you do in `[some method]`?

Comment: your method is exactly correct and this is update UI Main thread Faster

Comment: How many cells are we looking at?

Comment: @iDev, Why do you think using GCD is faster in this situation?

Comment: where you fetch data it is local or remote

Comment: You should provide more info about you specific problem. Are you loading data from a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

use this, it downloads multiple files in different threads.And its asynchronous.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //load image here
    });
```

If you want to load all images ,even the images which might be very down in tableView (say image at 20th row).Then viewDidLoad is perfect approach, or if you want to only load images that are currently to be shown, then download images in cellForRow:atIndexPath method.

OR,you can use [AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409122/afnetworking-downloading-multiple-files) to download multiple files much efficiently.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this in both the ViewDidLoad and cellForRow:atIndexPath, but they still load very slowly. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JohnSmith The answer as it stands now surely can't help: there's virtually no hint how you could improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

For loading images faster in table view cells you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

It is very simple to use. Just import the SDWebImage folder into your Xcode project. It contains a category on UIImageVIew. So on any imageView object just call the method **setImageWithURL** as illustrated below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
return cell;
```

}